# Does there exist a shorthand method for extracting the total hour count from a DateTime object in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Given -

```
$Foo = new DateTime();
```

Is it possible to extract the total number of hours (Non-fractional) from this value in a way besides something like...

```
$Bar = (($Foo->format('Y') * 365) + $Foo->format('d')) * 24
```

I was hoping for something like

```
echo $Foo->tHours(); /*Would output the total number of hours since the UNIX clock started.*/
```

Does something like this exist, or am I just kind of stuck cave-manning like the way I assigned the value to `$Bar` above?

Comment: confused but: `echo time()/(60*60);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` has a [`getTimestamp`](http://php.net/datetime.gettimestamp) method, which provides you with a UNIX timestamp (*number of seconds elapsed from the epoch*). So you could use that to more accurately compute numbers hours (just divide by `60*60`).

```
$Bar = floor($Foo->getTimestamp() / (60 * 60));

echo "Hours since $Foo->format('c') = $Bar"; // Hours since 2015-10-12T18:42:39-04:00 = 401302
```

Comment: Alrighty I can work with that... it's still a bit more cumbersome than for what I was hoping but what with we can get, we work. Thanks.

Comment: how is that cumbersome?

Comment: @Dagon maybe `/ 3600` is far too many keystrokes for them? No idea how I can possibly make it any less cumbersome.

Comment: No, what I mean is that... sorry I've come from a desktop development background. I was hoping for some magic method that just returned the total number of hours from the timestamp which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Will create your  own function:  `function magicWillFunction(){return floor($Foo->getTimestamp() / (60 * 60));  }` then `echo "Hours since $Foo->format('c') =".magicWillFunction();`